# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am a beginnner in mysql in Python. I would like to see all columns in my `my_sheet_detail`. I try this code:

```py
import datetime as dt

class DatabaseConnector(MyConnector):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DatabaseConnector, self).__init__("mypage_cz")

    def load_positions(self, date: dt.date, manual: bool = False) -> List[Route]:
        query = f"""
            SELECT  *
            FROM `my_sheet_detail` 
            """
        self.cur.execute(query, (date,))
        data = self.cur.fetchall()
        return data


def show_positions():
    DATE = [(2019, 3, 8)]
    for day in DATE:
        date = dt.date(day[0], day[1], day[2])
        dbc = DatabaseConnector()
        routes = dbc.load_positions(date)
    print(routes)
```

But I get an error `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`. Can you help me please? What other parameters do I need? I just need to print the whole database `my_sheet_detail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.cur.execute(query, (date,))
```

Why are you sending the date as a parameter when it's not being used in the query?
Remove it, it should work.